# Split first string from other strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string "1 2 3 4 5".., and I want to split the string into a stringA "1" and stringB "2 3 4 5".. I know that `string.split("\\ ", 1)` returns an array, but I have an user-defined amount of strings so I do not want to make a new array for each string that wants to be split and then take the first string of the array.

I'm quite new to Java so maybe an a little more indepth explanation/link to an explanation would be nice :)

EDIT ABOUT USER-DEFINED: I have a string 'input' which gets split by \\\n and the results are then put into an ArrayList of strings 'wort'.

I now want to further split each entry of 'wort' into two new ArrayLists 'wortFirst' and 'wortRemaining'.

All of that because I'm programming a vocabulary helper. It displays wortFirst and after the press of a solution button wortFirst's counterpart in wortRemaining. I plan to do that via an int i that's the same for both wortFirst(.get(i)) and wortRemaining(.get(i))

Comment: how many user-defined amount of strings? Add more details plz

Comment: Because if it were me, I would you string.Split() and store the result in an arraylist of strings

Comment: "*but I have an user-defined amount of strings so I do not want to make a new array for each string*" can you give us example of data from user and how you wish your program to handle it?

Comment: I program since Saturday, excuse my incompetence to form a question :)

Comment: So each line is in form of `keyWord rest of line`. Can we assume that each `keyWord` is unique? Also after you split this lines do you want to preserve order in input, or do you want to sort your data? Last question, can you use `Map` (which will create pairs of `keyWord -> rest of line`)? This will not let you easily use `get(i)` but you will be able to use `get(keyWord)` to access `rest of line`. You could also access set of all entries (all key->value pairs placed in map) and iterate over it if needed.

Comment: @Pshemo 
We can't really assume it, since I do not have anything to detect that, but I could tell the user not to put in the same keyWord twice (which he shouldn't do using common sense anyways)
Preserving the order in input is fine :)
`get(keyWord)` to access `rest of line` is actually better for me :) 
How would I do that Map you are talking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create dictionary which would split

```
keyWord rest of the line
```

into `keyWord` and `rest of the line`.

So lets say I have `input.txt` file which my app can read and its content looks like

```
foo description of foo
bar very long description of bar
```

Code which places it into map can look like this:

```
//I will fill my list with lines from file
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt"));

Map<String, String> dictionary = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                                //   LinkedHashMap - preserves order of insertion
                                //   if you don't need to preserve it use HashMap
                                //   if you want to sort elements by value of key 
                                //   use TreeMap

//lets split each line to key and value like you already do
//and put it into dictionary
for (String line : lines){
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+",2); //split on one (or more continues whitespaces)
                                            //but limit size of array to 2
    dictionary.put(tokens[0], tokens[1]);   //I assume "rest of the line" is mandatory, 
                                            //otherwise tokens[1] will not exist
}
```

You can print content of generated map by iterating over its set of entries (all key-value pairs):

```
//lets print content of map
for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : dictionary.entrySet()){
    System.out.println(pair.getKey()+" -> "+pair.getValue());
}
```

Now to get single element from map we can use `get(key)` which if key will not be present in map will return `null`, so if you would like to avoid `null` you can use `getOrDefault(key, alternativeValue)` so if `key` will not be present map will return `alternativeValue`:

```
String definition = dictionary.get("foo");
//if you want to return some predefined value in case "foo" will not be 
//present in dictionary you can use:
//String definition = dictionary.getOrDefault("foo","--there is no such word in dictionary--");
System.out.println("definition for key \"foo\" is: "+definition);
```

Output:

```
foo -> description of foo
bar -> very long description of bar
definition for key "foo" is: description of foo
```

---

To run this examples you will need these classes

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
```

Your IDE should be able to generate this imports for you (in Eclipse use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>)

---

Update:

Unfortunately `Map` doesn't have `get(index)` method. But when you filling your array with key-value pairs you can create `List` of `Map.Entry` elements which has `size` and `get` methods. To do it you can simply use copying constructor like

```
Random r = new Random();

List<Map.Entry<String, String>> allPairs = new ArrayList<>(dictionary.entrySet());
// list will be filled with content from this set          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
int randomIndex = r.nextInt(allPairs.size());
Map.Entry<String, String> randomEntry = allPairs.get(randomIndex);
System.out.println(randomEntry.getKey());
System.out.println(randomEntry.getValue());
```

Comment: Amazing!
Almost perfect for me, my problem is that I want to retrieve a random key of dictionary, just as I can with an ArrayList (arraylist.get(i), i is random) is that possible too with a Map?

Thank you so much anyway :)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite get it. What does that do?
is randomEntry.getKey() and .getValue() different each time I run that part of the code?

This is probably not gonna be very useful, but here's the source code of my program anyway: http://pastebin.com/tyz49bKA

Comment: @Skilly I am not sure what confuses you. In first comment under this answer you said "I want to retrieve a random key of dictionary". Code in "update" part shows how to store all key-value pairs from map (dictionary) in a list `new ArrayList<>(dictionary.entrySet())`. I also added example of how to random index which will be in range `[0, numberOfPairs)` - `r.nextInt(allPairs.size())`. Now based on that random index I am able to get key-value pair (entry) from list. Then I just print key and value from picked pair using `randomEntry.getKey()` and `randomEntry.getValue()`.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks for helping me with maps and such! My program works as it was intended now :)

Comment: @Skilly Good to hear it :)